# Filipina married to British wanting to live in Spain.Difficulty in applying Schengen Visa for a start

Tags: visas, schengen, spain, uk-citizens, filipino-citizens

I am a Filipina and we recently got married in the UK while I am on a short-term visa. Our plan is to go to Spain and live there. We have difficulty getting an accurate information about documents to provide which is supposedly just our passports, marriage certificate and travel insurance.

We are planning to apply for Schengen visa when we are back in the Philippines and yet I was rejected once before by Spain embassy when we plan to go as a Tourist and not married yet at that time. And now I am worrying I will be rejected again. What is the easiest way to go and process the Schengen Visa in which they are very straightforward with the rules? One of the thread said Czech Republic embassy in the Philippines. We are just confused in the EU rights of movement that we supposed to exercise when going to Spain.

Comment: Are you looking to move to Spain permanently?

Comment: @jacob-horbulyk , Yes that is our intention to move their permanently. But ofcourse i still need to get Schengen Visa in my country (Philippines). Been doing alot of researches that seems to be not straight forward with their rules.

Comment: Questions related to long term relocation are off-topic for this website and are better addressed at expatriates.stackexchange.com